# Unable to display data from heroku api to the Dom

Tags: javascript, react-native, api

I am building an application using React Native, and I want to use data from Heroku api. But when I make an API call and consolog the data I can see the data, but when I try to map them, nothing is coming out of the DOM. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much. Here below are my can and a screenshop.

**App.jsx:**

```
import react, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, useWindowDimensions, View, Text } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(
        "https://where2playdk.herokuapp.com/nearest?lat=55.70232019168349&lon=12.561693791177802"
      )
      .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
      .catch((error) => setIsError(error))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {places.map(({ name, distance }) => (
      <View>
        <Text>name</Text>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
          <Text>{distance}</Text> 
      </View>
      ))} 
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: data from api]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not updating the state here, only consoling the data,

```
      useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(
        "https://where2playdk.herokuapp.com/nearest?lat=55.70232019168349&lon=12.561693791177802"
      )
      .then((response) => setPlaces(response.data)) // here is the 
                                                     //mistake
      .catch((error) => setIsError(error))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

Comment: Ops thanks for pointing this out, I have tried many things and forgot this small detail.

Comment: These happens sometimes with us. Even I faced this many times. For us, its easy to debug others code rather than ours.

Answer (score 1):

I've haven't worked with React Native but if it's the same as regular React, then the first problem I see is that each element inside your map should have a key:

```
{places.map(({ name, distance }) => (
      <View key={name}>
        {/* ... */}
      </View>
      ))}
```

You also need to handle the loading state. Because when App first runs, places is undefined, so you are calling `undefined.map` which will probably throw an error. An early return would suffice.

```
if (!places) return <Text>Loading...</Text>
```

And I also don't see the `setPlaces()` being called, I assume you replaced it with the console log?

Comment: yes, react native has the same rules as react. I have missed replacing the console.log with the update function.